# Cloud Spanner — Equivalent Syntax for `SHOW TABLES`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

It's not clear how to run a query (or conduct an API call) to list all tables. Is this possible with Spanner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, looks like this is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/information-schema. In particular:

```
SELECT
  t.table_name
FROM
  information_schema.tables AS t
WHERE
  t.table_catalog = '' and t.table_schema = ''
```